# Is there any way to use multiple file dialogs to select files in VBA MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Right now: I have a form in a front end MS Access database. This form has three buttons, they all open file dialogs to select and import excel files into a back end database. For example one button is as follows:

```
    Private Sub Command0_Click()

'OPEN DIALOG BOX TO SELECT FILE

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
 .Filters.Clear
   .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx,*.xls"
   .Filters.Add "Access Databases", "*.accdb"
 .FilterIndex = 1      'Excel Files

 .AllowMultiSelect = True
 .ButtonName = "Open"
 .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Raw Files"
 .Title = "Select a File to Import"
 .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails

'IMPORT Excel file 1 FILE TO DATABASE

   If .Show Then

   'open database
Static acc As Access.Application
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim dbname As String
dbname = "C:\Users\Username\Documents\Back End.accdb"
Set acc = New Access.Application
acc.Visible = False
Set db = acc.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(dbname, False, False)
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase dbname

'import File


acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "ExcelFile1", .SelectedItems(1), True, "Sheet1!"

'close the workbook

acc.DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll

db.Close
Set db = Nothing

MsgBox ("Files have been successfully loaded. Proceed with analysis")


   End If
End With

End Sub
```

Is there any way that I can combine all three buttons into one button. So essentially what I'm looking for is a file dialog to pop up three times and select all the files I need and update the back end database without three different buttons.

Not sure if I articulated my question properly but any code or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wjat is the difference between the buttons? The db to import?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher there is no difference between the buttons they just import different files to create different tables.

Comment: Then select the table from a ComboBox/ListBox and reference the selection in the code.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking to do. I'm not looking for workarounds, I need this for a very specific reason/design.

Comment: That reason is a secret? If you don't want to select a table you can count the number of former imports and select the table by that or what do you want?

Comment: Just combine all the code and have it run in a single `Click` event? I feel like I'm missing something here...